# It is possible to detect when I stop pressing a key in Java?

Tags: java, keyboard, key

When I'm pressing a key i want to execute an instruction and when I stop pressing the key i want to execute another instruction. (Like the buttons on the android making setOnClickListener -> instruction for example). You can do in **Java** with the keys?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Which technology? WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, WebForms, ... This is more important than knowing that you are using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really hard to understand because you seem to be talking about keys and buttons at the same time. To detect that a button is pressed and then released you will need to override the onTouchEvent() method for the button. For keys/physical buttons on the device there are two methods to override:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg)
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg)
```

update: a more detailed explanation

```
boolean bKeyIsPressed;

@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg)
{
   switch (keyCode)
   {
     case THE_KEY_I_WANT:
        bKeyIsPressed = true;
        break;
   }
}

@Override public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg)
{
   switch (keyCode)
   {
     case THE_KEY_I_WANT:
        bKeyIsPressed = false;
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: It is ! I talk about buttons and keys at the same time because a i want programing in these two ways. Thanks

Comment: But i don't understand... explain to me just as is done with the keys?I understand "key".isPressed etc.. but not this !

Comment: This is Java - your question was tagged as Android, so that's how I answered it. The C# and Visual Studio tags seemed to indicate you have familiarity with that on Windows, but don't understand how to do it on Android.

Comment: Ups.. I fooled myself because I put the tag android is usual. I'm to develope an android app that will be the client. This bit of code is part of the server in C # ... sorry for the misunderstanding. but thanks for help so I know how to do in java! If you know in C # better.